# Parse keyboard input to text (with text editor like functionality, like support for backspace, left/right arrow & text selection capabilities)

Tags: library, c++, keyboard

I'm looking for a simple library that can take:

- A key name (like "L", "Numpad 5" etc)
- A series of booleans describing whether <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> is held

And outputs a string based on all previous fed in keys as if you were editing a document with a text editor.

Cross platform solutions would be preferable, but not necessary, but in the end I will need to cobble together some kind of Linux/Mac/Windows cross platform support in my application.

Thanks!